# How does crit affect beam spells and DOTs?

Tags: diablo-iii

How are beam spells(e.g. Desintegrate(wizard)) and DOTs (e.g. Haunt(witch doctor)) affected by critial strike chance?

I played with my wizard and i never saw a beam crit nor a DOT (e.g. meteor AoE after the impact). BUT i saw the DOT of the Meter affect my cooldowns via Critical Mass passive (chance to reduce cooldowns by 1 second upon crit). I didnt test the same with a beam spell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So now with 1.0.3 (maybe got added earlier) DoTs and beamspells crit, you **just don't see the delicious yellow numbers** but you can tell by them doing more damage than a usual tick would do. Also you can see by other spells profiting from the crits (e.g. Critical Mass passive of the wizard).

Answer (score 2):

According to some reading on the official forums, there is a mixed consensus on whether DoTs/channels are critting. Some, like you, have noticed the side effects of crits in some DoTs. Some people say they see the bigger yellow crit numbers with channeled spells, and some say they don't.

But the current Blizzard "Known Issues" post says that:

> **Combat**
>
> Damage over time debuffs are not benefiting from items that grant crit chance.
>
> [Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4916972036)

...so clearly DoTs are *meant* to crit, even if they aren't now. I suspect this applies to channeled spells too.

I do not see this topic mentioned on the current [Hotfixes List](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/5825330) or in the [Patch 1.0.2 info](http://www.diablofans.com/news/1213-diablo-3-patch-1029749-coming-soon/), so I am not sure when it will be further addressed.

Comment: In my experience, channels can *definitely* crit.

Answer (score 0):

Channels as ray of frost and desintegrate do crit ive been playing wizard since the release and yes they do. If you wanna see it clearly just cast release cast release this way youll see the damage of your beam and when it crit